# Can KCl (potassium chloride) salt substitute be used in a saline solution?

Tags: salt, potassium, saline

I recently had a tooth extraction and am rinsing my mouth with a syringe, and would like to use a saline solution instead of just warm water. But I only have potassium chloride, not sodium chloride. Is this still an effective saline solution for minimizing oral bacteria?